# Alarm Volume On A Motorola Citrus

Tags: alarm, volume, motorola

I'm using a Motorola Citrus.

Basically my alarm volume is low.  It is low in settings, but it is even lower, barely audible when I run a timer.

In settings I have the volume bar maxed out.

I also have the volume bar maxed out when I press the volume button on the upper right side of the phone

The phone is fully charged.

I'm using the sound of an alarm clock.

I'm new to Android and smart phones.

Any ideas on how I can make the alarm louder?

Thanks

Comment: If you go to Settings, then Sound, does it have multiple volume sliders? The Citrus should run software similar to my old Atrix 4G, and I remember it having a separate slider for Alarm volume (So you can have other volumes low, but your alarm can still be loud, etc). This is how modern devices handle it nowadays as well.

Comment: Under settings > sound and display settings I have: ringer volume, media volume.  Both volume bars are at the max.  In alarms there is a volume bar, also maxed. Under the timer, the thing I have the problem with, there is no volume control there

Comment: Hm... it's not normal Android behavior for the timer to ignore the alarm volume. Are you using the timer from the default Clock app, a Motorola bundle app, or a third-party app?

Comment: I'm using the alarm/timer app that came with the phone.  It is one app with two tabs, one for the alarm, one for the timer.

Comment: It seems like Motorola has shipped a weird alarm/timer app. I'd recommend looking in the Play Store for pretty much any well-rated alternative and see how it fares in comparison.